# Subset spatial points with a polygon

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (spolydf) and a SpatialPointsDataFrame (spointdf).  The layers have different extents, but overlap.

I can select points that fall within the polygon using

```
fall.within.poly <- spointdf[spolydf,]
```

How do I select points that fall outside the polygon? have tried

```
fall.outside.poly <- spointdf[-spolydf,]
```

but doesn't work. I'm mmissing something simple - any help please.

Comment: You may want to use function `over` to find which points fall in polygons.

Comment: Thank, but I'm looking for points that fall outside the polygon.

Comment: Yes I know, but both answers are linked. If you use `sp::over` you will keep all your points. Those over polygons will have polygons information, others will have NA. Then you can filter. Without you providing a reproducible example, I cannot show you.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit late but I had the same issue today so I though that I would post my solution using `gDifference()` from the `rgeos` package:

```
require(rgeos)
require(sp)

##create spdf
coords=expand.grid(seq(150,151,0.1),seq(-31,-30,0.1))
spdf=data.frame("lng"=coords[,1],"lat"=coords[,2])
coordinates(spdf) = ~lng+lat
proj4string(spdf)<- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
plot(spdf)

##create poly
poly1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(150.45,150.45,150.75,150.75,150.45),c(-30.75,-30.45,-30.45,-30.75,-30.75)))),ID=1)))
proj4string(poly1)<- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
lines(poly1)

##get difference
out = gDifference(spdf,poly1)
points(out,col="red",pch=16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found:

```
library(splancs)
set.seed(123)
my.shape <- matrix(runif(10), 5)
my.points <- data.frame(x=runif(500), y=runif(500))
my.points$in.shape <- 1:500 %in% inpip(my.points, my.shape)

plot(my.points[1:2], col=1 + my.points$in.shape)
polygon(my.shape)
```