# Spatial inverse subset using square brackets in R

Tags: r, spatial, rgeo-shapefile

I have a spatial point data frame -> spatial_points

and a polygon  -> spatial_poly

I can subset all points within the polygon using

```
subset_within <- spatial_points[spatial_poly,]  which is nice and intuitive.
```

But if I want to subset all points outside the polygon, I can't use

```
subset_ouside <- spatial_points[-spatial_poly,]
```

This question has been asked before, and the answer was to use `gDifference()` from the `rgeos` package.  Fine.

My question is, why does [ ] work for selecting within, not the inverse? I don't really understand the error message

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :    error in evaluating the
> argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': invalid argument
> to unary operator

Just curious. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is an example borrowed from [Subset spatial points with a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929603/subset-spatial-points-with-a-polygon)

```
require(rgeos)
require(sp)

##create spdf
coords=expand.grid(seq(150,151,0.1),seq(-31,-30,0.1))
spdf=data.frame("lng"=coords[,1],"lat"=coords[,2])
coordinates(spdf) = ~lng+lat
proj4string(spdf)<- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
plot(spdf)

##create poly
poly1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(150.45,150.45,150.75,150.75,150.45),c(-30.75,-30.45,-30.45,-30.75,-30.75)))),ID=1)))
proj4string(poly1)<- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

##get points withing polygon
points_within <-spdf[poly1,]  # this works

plot(spdf)
plot(poly1, add=T)
plot(points_within,col="blue",pch=16,add=T)

##get points outside polygon
points_outside <-spdf[-poly1,]  # this does not work - why??
```

In this simple example one can use `gDifference()`, which works in this example.  However, my SpatialPointDataframe is very large, and using gDifference crashes R.

Comment: Hi. Can you tell us which packages you are using? If you create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` in package `sp` and a `Polygon` in `sp`, then `spatial_points[spatial_poly,]` just throws an error. Could you maybe add the result of `dput(spatial_points)` and `dput(spatial_poly)` to your question?

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, what you describe does work.  Yes, using sp but also rgdal and raster.  Creating the points file is with coordinates(), and the shape file I import from an outside source.  Both are transformed using spTransform.  I ran dput() on both files and I get a very very long ascii file - can you tell me what I should be looking for?

Comment: Perhaps you could show a minimal example (i.e. make a polygon by co-ordinates and a few points by co-ordinates that reproduce the behaviour)

Comment: @Allan Cameron Example added.

Comment: Thanks. See my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `df[2, 1]` in R, you are actually calling a function. The function is `'['(df, 1, 2)`. It's just the parser hides this from you, and this allows you to write code in a more natural way.

If you think about it, the `[` operator does different things depending on the type of object you are using, even if the operations are conceptually similar. The actual code that returns a subset of a numeric vector is different from the code that returns the subset of a matrix, or of a list. In fact, there are some objects in R for which calling the `[` function doesn't make sense and isn't implemented. For example, if you try to call it on a function name:

```r
print[1]
#> Error in print[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

If you create a complex new class in R with various different members, you need to define what the `[` operator means, and you need to implement it. What does it mean to subset a `SpatialPoints` class by a `SpatialPolygon` class? R has no way to know that on its own, so when the author of the `sp` package created the `SpatialPolygons` class, he had to write the methods that do the subsetting based on the operands that are passed to the operator `[`. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/edzer/sp/blob/7871917583ade21f6073a1c8275e16c6a0eb865e/R/SpatialPolygons-methods.R#L114).

If you trace the logic through, you will see that in the case of `spdf[poly1,]`, the subset is determined by the use of other spatial functions, and boils down to

```r
which(!is.na(over(spdf, geometry(poly1))))
#> 39 40 41 50 51 52 61 62 63 
#> 39 40 41 50 51 52 61 62 63
```

And these numeric subsets are then used to subset the actual polygons to return a new object consisting of just the subset. That means we could get the `points_outside` in a similar way:

```
points_within  <- spdf[poly1,] 
points_outside <- spdf[which(is.na(over(spdf, geometry(poly1))))]

plot(spdf)
plot(poly1, add = TRUE)
plot(points_within, col="blue", pch = 16, add = TRUE)
plot(points_outside, col="red", pch = 16, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

But to answer your main question, which is why does `spdf[-poly1,]` not work, you have to realise that this actually means `'['(spdf, -poly1)`. For this to be evaluated, it would first be necessary to evaluate `-poly1`, but if you try that, then you get:

```r
-poly1
#> Error in -poly1 : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Of course, it doesn't really make sense to apply the `-` operator to a `SpatialPoints` object on its own. Take the points away from *what*?

In truth, it would be possible to write the function so it works in this way, but it would require a complex bit of non-standard evaluation. You could submit it as a feature request on that GitHub page, but personally I'd be happy using the function above.

I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks very much for that excellent explanation.  A couple bits I will need to digest, but it all makes perfect sense.  I think others will find this useful as well.  Cheers!